# Match overflowing box height to its parent box

Tags: css

I have box with nested image and div with text information. I'm doing simple CSS trick with positioning and display parameter changes on hover, so text box is only seen if hover on main box.

Here's my problem, text box has background with opacity, how can I match height of the box with background to its parent when it's show on hover.

Here's live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mamaduka/jDYu5/16/

Comment: Is the inline img intended ? I'm not sure I understand your problem, but did you try to add display:block to imgs and height:100% to texts ?

Comment: Your `.texts` divs are missing closing tags, which is creating unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Hi @mdi, tried but it doesn't paying nice with text box padding. Nathan sorry that was my mistake why recreating examples in jsFiddle.

Comment: Mamaduka: Actually, @mdi wasn't so far off. Check out the comments on Nick's solution. I think you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is give `texts` a height of `100%`

```
.box:hover .texts {
    display: block;
    height:100%;
}
```

Worked for me when I edited your fiddle.

Comment: What's irritating is that gap between the boxes that gets filled by the hover text. Any idea how to fix that, so it only covers the actual image? @Mamaduka, are these images always going to be 300x373?

Comment: Ahh, here's what we're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/jDYu5/25/ @mdi had part of the solution. Add `height:100%;` to `.box:hover .texts`, add `display:block;` to `img`, and then add `margin:8px;` to `.box`. EDIT: Oh, and I added closing tags to the `.texts` divs.

Comment: Tried that styling, but as @NathanArthur gap gets filled. No Nathan, image height would be changing.

Comment: @Mamaduka: Check the fiddle again. I hadn't saved it the first time. It's the right link now.

Comment: @Mamaduka: Changing the `height` from `88%` to `100%` doesn't break the solution.